# How to fix "NoMethodError (undefined method []' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/..."

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using rails and I am building a page that creates new "people"(people/new), but without using forms. Using javascript, I scan a page with user inputs and i end up with a javascript object looking like this:

```
obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
```

I then send a post request using javascript to the controller :

```
fetch('/people', {
    method: 'POST',
    user_params: stringified
})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Issue is, the console in the browser is indicating an error 500 :

```
POST http://localhost:3000/reports 500 (Internal Server Error)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Reading the terminal, I get the following error, which i think is the source of the problem :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/people_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

Here is my controller :

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token , only: [:create]

  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def create
    Person.create(name: params[:user_params][:name], age: params[:user_params][:age], city: params[:user_params][:city])
  end
end
```

I have tried changing the syntax in create in the controller :

```
params[:user_params[:age]]
```

instead of

```
params[:user_params][:age]
```

Which gives me the error

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
```

I believe however, having looked online for a long time that this change was wrong.

FYI here is what the variable "stringified" looks like when the inputs are empty

```
{"name":"","age":"","city":""}
```

I want the information sent (user_params) to be stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, your JSON doesn't follow the usual Rails format of having a top level 'user' key, e.g params[:user][:name]. You are creating the object with no top level key, so just do:

```
Person.create(name: params[:name], age: params[:age], city: params[:city])
```

Also you can look in the Rails console at what the params object looks like. If it still doesn't work paste your console output.

Edit:

Now it looks like your person is being created from your comments you need to do something afterwards. E.g

```
def create
   @person = Person.new(name: params[:name], age: params[:age], city: params[:city])

   if @person.save
     redirect_to @person
   else
     render :new
   end
end
```

That will require you to create a 'show' action for your controller as well and a view to go with it.

Comment: The error message has changed after changing the controller like you suggested : `Started POST "/people" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 14:45:35 +0100
Processing by PeopleController#create as */*
  ↳ app/controllers/people_controller.rb:16
  Person Create (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "people" ("city", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["city", "[:city]"], ["created_at", "2019-01-14 13:45:35.409632"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-14 13:45:35.409632"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/People_controller.rb:16``

Comment: and the second part: `   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/rPeople_controller.rb:16
No template found for PeopleController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 224ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)``

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your are attempting to access values that either are not there, or are organized differently than your code is expecting. When trying to access nested values in a Hash in Ruby, if at any point, one of the keys is missing or the value is `nil` it will error because `nil` does not have a method for `[]`, which you are chaining to access the next value.

If you do not want a 500 error for params missing you can use `dig` and it will safely return `nil` instead of throwing an error. But this is not the way you should do this, I'm including this to help give context as to *why* this could be happening to your code.

```
params.dig(:user_params, :name)
```

If you do want to throw an error because the `user_params` key **has** to be there then use `require`. Then to access the values you want for the creation you should use `permit` to only allow those values. This is to protect you from a malicious person inserting whatever other param they want, something as nasty as an admin flag if you don't protect yourself.

```
params.require(:user_params).permit(:name, :age, :city)
```

Comment: I'm seeing in the above conversation that it seems you figured this portion out. Hope this helps the next person. To help you, looks like you don't have a matching view file `app/views/people/create.(whatever_file_type(s)_you_need)`. Rails is looking for a file based on the name of the controller and action since you didn't specify a view file. It is taking an educated guess, and the guess was wrong so Rails is telling you.